# How to check a list is ordered using Fluent Assertions

Tags: c#, list, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I am writing some unit tests using specflow and need a way to check whether a list of objects is ordered by a specific property. Currently I am doing it like this, but I am not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

```
var listFromApi = listOfObjects;

var sortedList = listFromApi.OrderBy(x => x.Property);

Assert.IsTrue(listFromApi.SequenceEqual(sortedList));
```

Is there a nice way this can be done using Fluent Assertions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FluentAssertions: equivalence of sorted lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295767/fluentassertions-equivalence-of-sorted-lists)

Comment: See https://fluentassertions.com/documentation/#collections

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes.  You can use `BeInAscendingOrder` with a lambda.

```
listFromApi.Should().BeInAscendingOrder(x => x.Property);
```

For extra clarity at the expense of performance, you can also assert on content equivalence:

```
listFromApi.Should().BeEquivalentTo(listOfObjects)
    .And.BeInAscendingOrder(x => x.Property);
```

Answer (score 10):

It is possible to pass the options like:

```
listFromApi.Should().BeEquivalentTo(sortedList, opt => opt.WithStrictOrdering());
```