# How to verify that multiple sorts have been applied to a collection?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sorting, tdd, fluent-assertions

I'm implementing sortable columns on my Kendo grid and the user-expected behaviour is to allow multiple columns to be sorted at the same time.

Naturally, I'm starting off by writing a unit test to be able to verify that the sorting is (by default) first by `Ref` ascending, then `Name` ascending.

Test suppliers in question are here:

```
_context.Suppliers.Add(new Supplier { Ref = "abc", Name = "steve"});
_context.Suppliers.Add(new Supplier { Ref = "abc", Name = "bob"});    
_context.Suppliers.Add(new Supplier { Ref = "cde", Name = "ian"});    
_context.Suppliers.Add(new Supplier { Ref = "fgh", Name = "dan"});
```

Then I go and ask the test for my sorted suppliers.

Fluent assertions I know has the `BeInAscendingOrder` and `BeInDescendingOrder` methods, however even after looking through the documentation and [following possibly related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143875/how-to-check-a-list-is-ordered-using-fluent-assertions) I couldn't see an example of chaining sorting methods.

My current test verification is like this:

```
results.Should().HaveCount(4).And.BeInAscendingOrder(x => x.Ref)
           .And.BeInAscendingOrder(x => x.Name);
```

I was expecting the verification to work a bit like `LINQ` where it has `OrderBy(x => x.Ref).ThenBy(x => x.Name)`.

However when running the test, it is failing because it is expecting the collection to be ordered ascending by `Name` (the final sort assertion).

Is there a way to tell Fluent Assertions that the sorts should be applied in conjunction with one another and not just in sequence?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `ThenInAscendingOrder` so you might have to resort to `source.OrderBy(x => x.Ref).ThenBy(x => x.Name).ShouldBeEquivalentTo(results, options => options.WithStrictOrdering());` or something more verbose which checks the order explicitly.

Comment: Before assertions you usually create an expected value(colleciton in your case). Then as mentioned above FluentAssertions have `WithStrictOrdering` option that check that actual collection equivalent to and ordered as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I tried Fabio/Stuart's comments of using `WithStrictOrdering` and that worked for a time.

However when I came to change the sort order my tests kept passing instead of failing (because I'd changed the sort on my test but not the method).

The following worked wonderfully:

```
var resultsList = results.ToList();
var expectedResults = resultsList.OrderByDescending(x => x.IsSupplierInvalid)
                                        .ThenBy(x => x.Ref).ToList();
resultsList.Should().HaveCount(4).And.ContainInOrder(expectedResults);
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use this overload of `BeInAscendingOrder`:

```
BeInAscendingOrder(IComparer<T> comparer, string because = "", params object[] args)
```

and then create a `SupplierComparer` that inherits from `Comparer<Supplier>`.

Here is a complete example

```
class Supplier
{
    public string Ref { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class SupplierComparer : Comparer<Supplier>
{
    public override int Compare(Supplier x, Supplier y)
    {
        var compareRef = x.Ref.CompareTo(y.Ref);
        if (compareRef != 0)
        {
            return compareRef;
        }

        var compareName = x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
        if (compareName != 0)
        {
            return compareName;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}

public void MyTestMethod()
{
    var suppliers = new[]
    {
        new Supplier { Ref = "abc", Name = "steve" },
        new Supplier { Ref = "abc", Name = "bob" },
        new Supplier { Ref = "cde", Name = "ian" },
        new Supplier { Ref = "fgh", Name = "dan" }
    };

    var comparer = new SupplierComparer();
    suppliers.Should().BeInAscendingOrder(comparer);
}
```